# Omit specific JSON properties from being parsed when using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Google's GSON. I have a JSON data file like this:

```
{"NAME":"Joe",
"AGE":"18",
"DATA":[0,0,0,0,0,...]}
```

Where `DATA` is a very, very large array.

I would like to read the JSON file, but **omit** particular properties from being parsed. In the above case, I would like to omit reading `DATA` and hence receive a `JsonObject` that only contains `NAME` and `AGE`.

I have tens of thousands of these files, and I need to read the `NAME` and `AGE` fields of each. So clearly I don't need to parse `DATA`, which I feel is a huge waste of resources considering the amount of files I need to process.

Can this be achieved using Google's GSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it can. GSON supports annotations.**

Create a simple POJO, if you don't already have.

```
public class Person {
    @Expose @SerializedName("NAME")
    public String name;
    @Expose @SerializedName("AGE")
    public String age; // because your snippet showed "18" in quotes

    // getters and setters, if you like
}
```

You should edit your class and use the `@Expose` annotations properly.

When you instantiate you `Gson` object to convert the JSON into a `Person` object, use this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

That way, Gson will know which fields to look and which to ignore.

**EDIT:** the attributes in `Person` are `public` because I'm assuming you won't use getters and setters.

Comment: Is it necessary to use its serialization features? I quite literally just need to get a `JsonObject` and then use `get()` to get the name and do my stuff. Of course if there is no other way then this does sound like a good way to achieve this.

Comment: I know the `JsonObject` approach seems simpler, but this POJO class would have 4 lines of code. If there is any other way, it's not well-documented and I'd fear losing compatibility in the future.